# Facing issue in Biometric Authentication in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I implemented biometric authentication using java . it authenticate first time correctly . when i try to authenticate second time it does not call its callback also enable & disable switch for biometric did not work

I tried to authenticate secondtime using biometric after successfully authentication . but it does not authenticate user , it remain on same screen

Comment: Can you share at least parts of your code? There may be different reasons the callback is not called!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you’re having trouble with biometric authentication in your Android app.
One possible reason why it’s not working the second time is that you might be reusing the same instance of BiometricPrompt.
You should create a new instance of BiometricPrompt each time you want to authenticate the user.

Another possible reason why it’s not working is that you might be using an incorrect cancellation signal when dismissing the dialog.
You should use a new cancellation signal each time you show the dialog.